# Passing Dates in batches of 7 days to a stored proc until the last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have stored proc which will be used to retrieve data that will be imported into another table for a long period. **'2020-01-01' to '2022-02-28'** I want to do this in batches of 7 days. I don't want to manually run the PROC and pass 7 days range for a 2 year period.

Pseudo example:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.MyImportedData
INSERT INTO dbo.MyImportedData
EXEC [dbo].[MyLongRangeData]
          @StartDate = @StartDate,
          @EndDate = @EndDate -- First 7 Day Period (2020-01-01 to 2020-01-07)

INSERT INTO dbo.MyImportedData
EXEC [dbo].[MyLongRangeData]
          @StartDate = @StartDate,
          @EndDate = @EndDate -- second 7 Day Period (2020-01-08 to 2020-01-14) --Doing this until 2022-02-28.
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Why don't you rewrite the stored procedure (or create a copy) to do the looping for you, so you don't have to call it 100+ times? Also how exactly do you define a "7-day period"? Jan 1 -> Jan 7 2020, Jan 8 -> Jan 14 2020, ... pretty clear so far. But what happens when you hit Jan 1 2021?

Comment: May I ask why you are not trying to achieve this thing using SSIS? This will let you define the batch size in rows instead of dates, which is much better.

Comment: @Philippe Well, not if the report is weekly sales or something like that, where number of rows is actually part of what you want to highlight, not stabilize / smooth out.

Comment: @Aaron: Maybe I misunderstood the problem, but from I see there, the task is to copy lots of data from one table to another table and to split the workload in batches, the OP wants to only copy 7 days at once. As far as I understood it, it has nothing to to with highlighting .

Also: Depending on the content and the indexing, it might be easier to just use an ID column for the select. If nearly no IDs are missing, then selecting on the PK can improve the performance a lot.

Comment: @Philippe We just don't know, we don't have any clue what the procedure does (maybe it aggregates?) or why it currently takes a date range at all. Are we sure it's simply to handle fewer rows at a time? Maybe? Maybe not? Maybe the source data is summarized or otherwise periodic and already contains a consistent number of rows per <any time frame>? Maybe? Maybe not?

Comment: Okay so the PROC is used by other programs which normally just runs for a short period range and has some aggregation that it does. Now for this purpose it's going to be a once off thing. Reason for the 7 day range, is for performance reasons. If you go beyond 7, 10 days it raises eyebrows of some individuals. @AaronBertrand yes that's more like what's to be done and thanks your solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want simple 7-day blocks and don't need to align to the first day of the year or fiscal periods, you could do a simple loop, something like this:

```
DECLARE @d date = '20200101', @e date;

WHILE @d <= '20220228'
BEGIN
  SET @e = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @d);

  INSERT dbo.MyImportedData(<always list columns here!>)
    EXEC [dbo].[MyLongRangeData] @StartDate = @d, @EndDate = @e;

  SET @d = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @d);
END
```

But better would be to re-write the procedure (or create a new one) to handle 7-day chunks for you across any date range, so you don't have to call it 100 times.